# Used setText for EditText box and onClick thinks it's null

Tags: java, javascript, android, android-edittext

I am hoping this is an easy fix. I can't figure out what I am missing here.  This is a login form and I have it remembering the previous login email with sharedpreferences.  The editText box has the email prepopulated in the onCreate but the onClick thinks the editText field is empty.  Any ideas?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_email_address);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blogin);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.invalid_email);


    // register listeners
    newuser.setOnClickListener(this);
    login.setOnClickListener(this);
    app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    String restoredemail = app_preferences.getString("username", null);
    if (restoredemail != null) {
        email.setText(restoredemail);

    email.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (email.getText().toString()
                    .matches("[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+")
                    && s.length() > 0) {
                text.setText("valid email");
                valid_email = true;
                //user_email = email.toString();
            } else {
                text.setText("invalid email");
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        }
    });
}

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.blogin:
        if (valid_email == true) {
            new AttemptLogin().execute();   
        }else{
```

Comment: Have you debugged to make sure its not `null` and you sure your `regex` is correct?

Comment: When I run the app you can see it's not null, it displays the email address. If I click the login button that field is still null.  If I erase part the email and retype it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it.

I have a addTextChangedListener to check if a valid email is being entered before submitting. Since the text wasn't changing (being typed in) it wasn't registering.  I don't know if this might help someone someday but here is revised code.   Thank you to all who posted help on this.

```
String restoredemail = app_preferences.getString("username", null);
    if (restoredemail != null) {
        email.setText(restoredemail);
        valid_email = true;
        text.setText("valid email");
    }else{  

        email.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (email.getText().toString()
                    .matches("[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+")
                    && s.length() > 0) {
                text.setText("valid email");
                valid_email = true;
                //user_email = email.toString();
            } else {
                text.setText("invalid email");
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        }
    });
}

}
```